# Google Chrome installation error fall into Python 2.7 on Centos 7

Tags: google-chrome, installation, centos

I have the following error messages while installing Google Chrome in Centos 7.  I also tried to upgrade to Python 3.3. Also, I didn't press any key to cancel the process.  But, this error still there.  Any workaround suggestion?

```
 ...
 redhat-lsb-submod-multimedia  x86_64  4.1-24.el7          base            15 k
 redhat-lsb-submod-security    x86_64  4.1-24.el7          base            15 k
 spax                          x86_64  1.5.2-11.el7        base           259 k
 systemtap-sdt-devel           x86_64  2.4-16.el7_0        updates         58 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+79 Dependent packages)

Total size: 72 M
Total download size: 15 k
Installed size: 260 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for base
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down", line 61, in main
    fo = PyCurlFileObject(opts.url, opts.filename, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1258, in __init__
    self._do_open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1589, in _do_open
    self._do_grab()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1723, in _do_grab
    self._do_perform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1517, in _do_perform
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt


Exiting on user cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi my temporary solution was edit in:

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py

commenting entire block:

elif errcode in (42, 55, 56):

to end:

raise KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Consider adding reasoning behind your answer, why it works and what was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py` Change the line number 1510 `elif errcode in (42, 55, 56):` to `elif errcode == 42:`

Answer (score 0):

Comment this `elif errcode in (42, 55, 56):` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py` on line no.1510